# youtube.com and html5 video tag

Tags: html, video, tags, youtube

I have a question. I know youtube has supported html5 for some time, so I just tried disabling the adobe flash plugin and took a look at the page source. I found no video tag. Could anybody explain that?

Comment: They probably use Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using chrome, after disabling Flash, I do get a warning when trying to watch videos ("You need Flash!"), but it detects that I don't have flash, and uses the HTML5 version instead. If you use Chrome, you can look at the DOM with the developer tools (F12), and you'll indeed find a video tag in the video-container div, e.g.

```
<video class="video-stream" x-webkit-airplay="allow" src="http://o-o.preferred.twtelecom-dfw1.v15.lscache5.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?sparams=cp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cexpire&amp;fexp=900161&amp;itag=43&amp;ip=207.0.0.0&amp;signature=55FCBF36A597656FECBEC8E78051B3BD30EE8D97.8F8D573710D767EAF4429FBC54C940DF7611A1BE&amp;sver=3&amp;ratebypass=yes&amp;source=youtube&amp;expire=1330650696&amp;key=yt1&amp;ipbits=8&amp;cp=U0hSRVZQTl9OUENOMl9OSlJHOlBlcHJOMW9PSHhH&amp;id=381980b5e867a1c5" data-youtube-id="OBmAtehnocU"></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

For almost everything Google does on the web they use javascript.  Most likely what is happening is that they test the browser to make sure it supports HTML5 video, they then load the the video dynamically using javascript.

To verify, use a web browser tool to inspect the current html as it's shown, not as it's sent to the browser.

And as Marius noted, be sure to have [HTML5 enabled](http://www.youtube.com/html5)